# Check duplication record from one table and duplication record insert to another table using php script

Tags: php, mysql, apache, htdocs

I have two below tables

1)CandidateDetails

```
EmployeeId  FirstName       LastName    Mobile          Email     BatchId
1           fn1             ln1         123456789       Email1      75
2           fn2             ln2         123456790       Email2      75
3           fn3             ln3         123456791       Email3      75
4           fn4             ln4         123456792       Email4      75
```

2)DuplicateCandidate

```
EmployeeId  FirstName       LastName    Mobile          Email     BatchId
```

My requirement is if EmployeeId is already available in **CandidateDetails** table then duplicate record to insert into **DuplicateCandidate**

Below is PHP script only for inserting array to **CandidateDetails** table, but i am not able to check the condition for if employee id is duplication then that record to insert into another **DuplicateCandidate** table.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Custom-Header, Origin, Content-Type , Authorisation , X-Requested-With");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 ");

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($decoded);
 $id=$_GET['id'];

function conn() {
  $dbhost = "xxxx";
  $user = "xxx";
  $pass = "xxx";
  $db = "xxxx";
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx', $user, $pass);
  return $conn;
}
$db = conn();
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);                  
$p = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO CandidateDetails(EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName, Mobile,Email,BatchId)VALUES(:EmployeeId,:FirstName,:LastName,:Mobile,:Email,'$id')");
                   
foreach ($decoded as $item) {
  $p->execute($item);
}

echo json_encode(true);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Custom-Header, Origin, Content-Type , Authorisation , X-Requested-With");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 ");

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($decoded);
$id = $_GET['id'];

function conn()
{
    $dbhost = "x.x.x.x";
    $user = "x";
    $pass = "x";
    $db = "x";
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=x;dbname=x', $user, $pass);
    return $conn;
}
$db = conn();
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
foreach ($decoded as $item)
{
    echo $item['EmployeeId'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM CandidateDetails WHERE EmployeeId = " . $item['EmployeeId'];
    //$result = $conn-                         >query($sql);
    echo $item['EmployeeId'];
    echo $sql;
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    //echo $result;
    //echo $result->num_rows;
    $count = $result->rowCount();
    echo $count;
    if ($count > 0)
    {
        //DuplicateCandidate
        echo "duplicte results";
        //$p = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO CandidateDetailsLog(EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName, Mobile,Email,BatchId)VALUES(:EmployeeId,:FirstName,:LastName,:Mobile,:Email,'$id')");
        $p = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO CandidateDetailsLog(EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName, Mobile,Email,BatchId)
                                      VALUES ('" . $item['EmployeeId'] . "', '" . $item['FirstName'] . "',
                                                      '" . $item['LastName'] . "', '" . $item['Mobile'] . "', '" . $item['Email'] . "',
                                                       '" . $id . "')");

        $p->execute();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "0 results";
        //$p = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO CandidateDetails(EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName, Mobile,Email,BatchId)VALUES(:EmployeeId,:FirstName,:LastName,:Mobile,:Email,'$id')");
        $p = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO CandidateDetails(EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName, Mobile,Email,BatchId)
                                      VALUES ('" . $item['EmployeeId'] . "', '" . $item['FirstName'] . "',
                                                      '" . $item['LastName'] . "', '" . $item['Mobile'] . "', '" . $item['Email'] . "',
                                                       '" . $id . "')");

        $p->execute();
    }

}

$o = $db->prepare("UPDATE BatchDetailsInfo SET BatchStatus='B2' WHERE BatchId='$id'");
$o->execute();

echo json_encode(true);

?>
```

Comment: got help from here : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: This code is dangerous and includes [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) vulnerabilities

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer may do the job, it has several [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) vulnerabilities, including `$_GET['id']` (which should not be trusted - a malicious actor could put anything in here including a SQL command to clear your database), and the JSON harvested from `php://input` (likewise - even if it's valid JSON you could hide commands to delete data in here).  Parameter escaping (as your original example) is the way to go.

```
<?php

/* Your headers etc here*/

///Build a database connection
function db_conn() {
    /* Your Mysql setup with user/pass/db etc in a PDO object here*/
    $db=new PDO('mysql:host=x;dbname=x', $user, $pass);
    //You might want to set this here (for all connections:)
    //$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $db;
}

///Search the candidate table for an entry for the given ID
function db_employeeCandidateExists($db,$dangerEmployeeId) {
    $stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT EmployeeId FROM CandidateDetails WHERE EmployeeId=?');
    $stmt->execute([$dangerEmployeeId]);
    $result=$stmt->fetchAll();//We're expecting 0 rows (not found) or 1 row with the ID if it's a dup
    return count($result)>0;
}

///Add a row to the DuplicateCandidate table
function db_addDuplicate($db,$dangerRow,$dangerBatchId) {
    //All columns you want to fill out - layed out to be visually obvious how many there are
    $cols=['EmployeeId',
        'FirstName',
        'LastName',
        'Mobile',
        'Email',
        'BatchId'];
    //Values for the above columns - layed out to be visually equal to above
    // don't forget
    $vals=[$dangerRow['EmployeeId'],
        $dangerRow['FirstName'],
        $dangerRow['LastName'],
        $dangerRow['Mobile'],
        $dangerRow['Email'],
        $dangerBatchId];
    //The parameters can use a count of the cols (above)
    $params=substr(str_repeat('?,',count($cols)),0,-1);

    $stmt=$db->prepare('INSERT INTO DuplicateCandidate ('.
        implode(',',$cols).
        ') VALUES ('.
        $params.
        ')');

    $stmt->execute($vals);
    //todo: You might want to check there are no SQL errors reported here
}

///Add a row to the CandidateDetails table
function db_addCandiate($db,$dangerRow,$dangerBatchId) {
    //All columns you want to fill out - layed out to be visually obvious how many there are
    $cols=['EmployeeId',
        'FirstName',
        'LastName',
        'Mobile',
        'Email',
        'BatchId'];
    //Values for the above columns - layed out to be visually equal to above
    // don't forget
    $vals=[$dangerRow['EmployeeId'],
        $dangerRow['FirstName'],
        $dangerRow['LastName'],
        $dangerRow['Mobile'],
        $dangerRow['Email'],
        $dangerBatchId];
    //The parameters can use a count of the cols (above)
    $params=substr(str_repeat('?,',count($cols)),0,-1);

    $stmt=$db->prepare('INSERT INTO CandidateDetails ('.
        implode(',',$cols).
        ') VALUES ('.
        $params.
        ')');

    $stmt->execute($vals);
    //todo: You might want to check there are no SQL errors reported here
}

///Get JSON from input and decode it into an associative array
function getJson() {
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    return json_decode($json, true);
}

$db = db_conn();
//You might want to set this inside the `conn()` method for all usage?
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// *** *** Dangerous CONTENT *** ***
// Both $id (presuambly an integer) and $json (an associative array of data)
// are user-provided and therefore the cannot be trusted - you NEED to escape these
// values before using them in SQL
$dangerBatchId = $_GET['id'];
$dangerJson = getJson();

foreach($dangerJson as $dangerItem)
{
    if (db_employeeCandidateExists($db,$dangerItem['EmployeeId'])) {
        //Duplicate
        db_addDuplicate($db,$dangerItem,$dangerBatchId);
        echo 'Applicant '.$dangerItem['EmployeeId']." was a duplicate\n";
    } else {
        db_addCandiate($db,$item,$dangerBatchId);
        echo 'Applicant '.$dangerItem['EmployeeId']." added\n";
    }
}
// Further processing
```

I've used position parameter escaping (`?`) which should also work with MySQL.  Named position escaping (`:id`) is probably better, but doesn't allow me to quickly generate all parameters (build the `$params` string), and the database I tested against doesn't support them.

After separating the components into functions (as I've done), you'll notice we have a bit of a grouping of functions beginning with `db_`... you might, instead, configure bundling these into a class.  At that point you could avoid passing `$db` as the first parameter because you could internally share that in the class.  **But** that's a completely different topic and out of scope of your original question.